# How to view array values in laravel 5?

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I had an array from controller named $data which contain this array...

```
array:4 [▼
0 => "9 May 2011"
1 => "24 0 2013"
2 => "12 0 2013"
3 => "7 April 2014"
]
```

I want to display the output in blade view using foreach like this:

```
 @foreach($data as $value)  
     <td>{{ $value }}</td>
 @endforeach
```

However, I got this error in the browser.

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

What is not right with foreach output?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ }}` automatically adds function `htmlspecialchars()` Try using `{!! !!}`

```
 @foreach($data as $value)  
    <td>{!! $value !!}</td>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Yes, it produce the output and eliminating the error..I don't know those codes will acted differently..Thanks @Leena Patel

Answer (score -1):

I think when you are using `{{ $value }}` that is trying to loop over the whole array, e.g. `Array[ A =1, B=2 ....]` and so on. When you are doing that `foreach` loop you are looping the whole array not the content.

What you could do is name it so when you loop through you would do:

```
 @foreach($data as $array)  
     {{ $array[0][value] }}
 @endforeach
```

This would look for the index at 0 then the element named `value` at this index.

Also there is a [good article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52915181/10527545) which talks about selecting a value inside the index, which may help you too.